# name 'Label' is not defined ... tkinter in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

pip install tkinter
Collecting tkinter
Note: you may need to restart the kernel to use updated packages.
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tkinter (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tkinter

```
from tkinter import*
import tkinter as tk
#from PIL import Image,ImageTk
#from tkinter import messagebox
#import smtplib
#from tkinter import scrolledtext as st
root = tk.Tk()
root.title('Email Sender')
root.geometry('400x300')
root.maxsize(400,300)
root.minsize(400,300)

header = Label(root,bg="orange",width=300,height=2)
header.place(x=0,y=0)
h1 = Label(root,text="Email Sender",bg="orange",fg="black",font=('verdana',13,'bold'))
h1.place(x=135,y=5)
```

---

```
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-952991216055> in <module>
----> 1 header = Label(root,bg="orange",width=300,height=2)
      2 header.place(x=0,y=0)
      3 h1 = Label(root,text="Email Sender",bg="orange",fg="black",font=('verdana',13,'bold'))
      4 h1.place(x=135,y=5)

NameError: name 'Label' is not defined
```

Comment: use tk.Label to create labels

Comment: Just `Label` should work, too. Are you doing this in a `.py` file or directly in the interactive shell?

Comment: The error doesn't match the code posted. Please make sure to post a working, accurate [mre]

Comment: Is there a file named `tkinter` in your directory of the project?

Comment: I'm doing this with notepad (jupyter) @tobias_k

Comment: I used it (tk.Label) 
NameError: name 'tk' is not defined
@AdnanAkram

Comment: @Bashar in the first two lines, you are first calling "from tkinter import *", and then again you are writing "import tkinter as tk".... this is a foolish thing to do. You should write anyone of these. Either use "from tkinter import *"  or "import tkinter as tk".

Comment: in code you show `Label(..)` but error shows `Label.tk(...)` - it seems you run different code then you show. And it can means you can run code which doesn't have `from tkinter import *`. Better copy code from your question, put it in `Jupiter` and run it. BUT one thing - if you run Juputer on server then it may not have installed `tkinter` - and if it has installed `tkinter` then `tkinter` will try to display it on monitor directly connected to server - not on your local monitor.

Answer (score 1):

[`Label`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Dg7U.png)
first I used the notepad jupyter it was showing error messages
then I write it in the py shell it ran successfully
by using import tkinter import * and from tkinter as tk

Comment: into jupyter it has not solved, But in python shell, it ran successfully @CoolCloud

Comment: Hmmm, I'm not sure as to why, try googling it though, you might find something useful